# android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED does not work

Tags: android, android-studio

I want my application to start at bootup, but the following code does not work. I have seen few more similar threads, but unable to find a solution that works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.com.blynq.player">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:name="app.com.blynq.services.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

My Broadcast receiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(pushIntent);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something very trivial ?
Is this combination of permissions I've used are unusual ?

Comment: ["Only receivers who have been granted this permission (by requesting it with the <uses-permission> tag in their AndroidManifest.xml) will be able to receive the broadcast."](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the completed boot permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```