# How to Launch an App After Rebooting / Startup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, startup, boot

I've read some of the threads here explaining about launching an app after startup such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup) but it didn't work for me.

Here is MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

AfterBootReceiver.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AfterBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "AfterBootReceiver - boot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest with the permission code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.liorle.startappafterboot">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AfterBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name= "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My questions is: does any of you see any problem with this code? how to make the receiver receive the boot action from within the main activity?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start an Application on startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Comment: No, I wrote above the the thread you mentioned didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register the receiver outside of your main Activity (in your Manifest), Android will not know that your BroadcastReceiver exists until your Activity is started. You will also need to create your own BroadcastReceiver implementation for this purpose.

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You may start yourt main Activity from inside your newly created BroadcastReceiver (BootCompletedReceiver).

Your application will also need to request the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Thanks but if I don't have a BroadcastReceiver inherited class, what do I need to register?

Comment: Hey, I just tried your suggestion and nothing happened :-(

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show your updated code?

Comment: Does your onReceive() get fired? Looks okay to me now.

Comment: Try to debug your onReceive() function and look for the actual value of intent.getAction(), maybe your if clause does not match?

Answer (score 0):

Your launcher is not listening for the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your apps current state - the main activity needs to be running to listen to the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast. Your manifest needs to have something registered that tells the ecosystem to activate the activity / receiver.

Comment: Thank you, but I changed according to your suggestion, uploaded the apk, rebooted my device and nothing happened :-(

Comment: Sorry about that - I'll see if I can review some code later and get something running

Comment: I have tried looking into my code, but that code was signed with the system signature, giving the app a higher security level. I have been looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272823/android-permission-receive-boot-completed-does-not-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android - I will keep on looking for you as well